# How to change default layout in Laravel8, livewire2 app?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I made in Laravel8, livewire2 3 layouts :
resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php, resources/views/layouts/frontpage.blade.php,
resources/views/layouts/personal.blade.php and removed original layouts.app.blade.php.

But opening dashboard page I got error :

```
View [layouts.app] not found. (View: /resources/views/dashboard.blade.php)
```

Which has default content :

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <x-jet-welcome />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

1. Can I specify layout in file above ?
2. Here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components I read :

> If you want to specify a default layout other than the layouts.app,
> you can override the livewire.layout config option.
>
> 'layout' => 'app.other_default_layout'

But I did not find any “livewire.layout” file in my project. How can I create it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should publish the livewire config file using the command

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
```

next, you can find it in config/livewire.php

Comment: I created with command config/livewire.php
and modified :
    'layout' => 'layouts.frontend',

and cleared all cach
but I got error 
View [layouts.app] not found.
anyway

Comment: can you post the app-layout blade component??? look for any @extends directive there

Comment: Aside from changing the over-arching default. You can also use `->layout('layouts.base');` on the method where the livewire view is called to change layouts for specific Livewire routes. See here: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#custom-layout

Answer (score 1):

first publish the **command** :
php artisan livewire:publish --config

go **to** :
config/livewire.php

**replace** this :
'layout' => 'layouts.app'

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem (even in Livewire 3) with a shortcut:

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.view-note')
        ->layout(Auth::guest() ? 'layouts.guest' : 'layouts.app');
}
```